# Writing basics かくときのきほん

Tags: words

My textbook has a section titled :

Writing Basics かくときのきほん

I'm trying to break down the hiragana.

かく means "to write" and きほん means "basic" , but I can't seem to find the meaning of the ときの in the middle.

What does it mean here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This とき (時 in kanji) means "when", so 書くときの基本 is like "Basics When Writing". の is a noun-linking particle, which is necessary because 基本 is a noun and とき needs to modify 基本 adjectivally.

Similar examples:

- 桜を見たときの思い出
  memories of when I saw cherry blossoms
- 会社を辞めたときの話
  the story of when I left the company